# Console de execução trava ao fazer muitas leituras no modo de depuração!

Tags: c#, debug

Na tentativa de depurar o código em busca de erros, muita das vezes preciso entrar com os dados solicitados, porém nem sempre é possível chegar ao final do programa pois a execução do debug via "F10" ou "F11" (se puderem dizer a diferença) trava impossibilitando a leitura dos próximos dados.

Não sei o motivo pelo qual isso ocorre e também não encontrei nada a respeito.
Se puderem me ajudar com isso ficarei grato.

Segue uma imagem do problema na execução:

[image: Console Executando em Modo Debug]

```
using System;

namespace SomaMedia
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string nome_candidato = " ";
            int qt_eleitores = 0, qt_brancos = 0, qt_indecisos = 0, qt_intencoes;
            int cont = 0, maior = 0, menor = 0;
            double percentual_intencoes = 0, percentual_indecisos = 0, percentual_brancos = 0;
            int? cod_candidato = null;

            while (cod_candidato != 0)
            {
                Console.Write("QUANTIDADE DE ELEITORES: ");
                qt_eleitores = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.Write("CÓDIGO DO CANDIDATO: ");
                cod_candidato = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine();

                if (cod_candidato == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Console.Write("NOME DO CANDIDATO: ");
                nome_candidato = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.Write("INTENÇÕES DE VOTO: ");
                qt_intencoes = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.Write("VOTOS EM BRANCO: ");
                qt_brancos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.Write("VOTOS INDECISOS: ");
                qt_indecisos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine();

                if (cont == 0)
                {
                    maior = qt_intencoes;
                    menor = qt_intencoes;
                }

                if (qt_intencoes > maior)
                {
                    maior = qt_intencoes;
                }

                if (qt_intencoes < menor)
                {
                    menor = qt_intencoes;
                }

                percentual_intencoes = ((qt_intencoes / qt_eleitores) * 100);
                percentual_brancos = ((qt_brancos / qt_eleitores) * 100);
                percentual_indecisos = ((qt_indecisos / qt_eleitores) * 100);

                Console.WriteLine($"{percentual_intencoes}% - {nome_candidato}");


            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{percentual_brancos}% - VOTOS EM BRANCO");
            Console.WriteLine($"{percentual_indecisos}% - VOTOS INDECISOS");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Caro Ramon, poderia postar seu código para analisarmos? Obrigado. Por sua imagem consigo ver que o processo está parado em um breakpoint.

Comment: Ramon, isso *"via "F10" ou "F11" (se puderem dizer a diferença) trava impossibilitando a leitura dos próximos dados."* não ficou claro pra mim, pode explicar melhor? Sobre o **F10** e **F11**, se estiver na chamada de um método (por exemplo `var x = ObterValor();` e usar **F11**, o debugger vai entrar no método "ObterValor", se usar **F10**, não entra no método, só executa e vai para a próxima linha.

Comment: Paulo, como solicitado, segue o código.
Porém isso acontece com qualquer código que eu tente depurar.

Comment: Ricardo, seguinte:

Ali haviam mais dados para serem lidos, certo? 
Porém depois de eu digitar o que foi solicitado o console não é fechado para continuar a execução, me obrigando a sair pressionando o "x" e executar o código novamente..

As vezes vai, as vezes não.
Deu para entender?

Comment: @RamonAlmeida Você aperta a tecla no Visual Studio ou no console? Fez com F5 também?

Comment: @Maniero Deu certo aqui! 
Eu estava esperando que ao dar entrada, a tela fosse fechada como no inicio para que eu pudesse seguir com a depuração.

Mas é só clicar no Visual Studio e apertar o F10 que continua normal.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramon o que está ocorrendo não é um problema, mas um mau entendimento da execução de um programa via Console do Visual Studio.

Pela sua imagem consigo ver a **seta amarela**, que indica que seu código está parado no breakpoint esperando você continuar a execução da depuração.

Você disse nos comentários que você é obrigado a apertar o **X** para rodar o processo novamente, porém na verdade o que está ocorrendo é que o programa está parado na execução da depuração esperando sua interação.

> Para resolver seu "problema", volte ao código e continue a execução do seu programa pressionando F5, F10 ou F11.

**Função do F5**

Continua a execução do programa até o fim ou até encontrar um próximo breakpoint no fluxo do algoritmo.

**Função do F10**

Executa linha por linha do algoritmo sem entrar nos métodos que estejam ao longo do fluxo. Por exemplo:

```
int numero = 0;

//Outros códigos que alteram o valor da variável numero

if (numero > 10)
{
    Calcular(numero);
}
```

Caso a gente aperte F10 quando a depuração estiver no método `Calcular(numero)` serão executados todos os códigos dentro da função, mas não iremos ver o que está ocorrendo dentro dela.

**Função do F11**

Executa linha por linha do algoritmo, mas nesse caso nós entramos nos métodos que estejam ao longo do fluxo. Por exemplo:

```
int numero = 0;

//Outros códigos que alteram o valor da variável numero

if (numero > 10)
{
    Calcular(numero);
}
```

Caso a gente aperte F11 quando a depuração estiver no método `Calcular(numero)` iremos passar dentro da definição do método Calcular, podendo analisar o que está acontecendo nessa interação do fluxo do algoritmo, analisando atribuição de valores, chamadas de outros métodos, execuções de regras, etc.

Comment: Sua explicação assim como a do Maniero me ajudaram..
Realmente era uma mau entendido da minha parte (imaginei que fosse isso mesmo).
Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Por nada meu caro, tamo junto!